# C# How to print combinations that add upto given number?

Tags: c#, recursion, dynamic, numbers, addition

I am trying to implement "Count of different ways to express N as the sum of other numbers" problem with C# using dynamic progamming.
My method looks like:

```
 static int howManyWays(int n) 
    { 
        int [] safe= new int[n + 1]; 

        // base cases 
        safe[0] = safe[1] = safe[2] = 1; 
        safe[3] = 2; 

        // iterate for all values from 4 to n 
        for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++) 
            safe[i] = safe[i - 1] + safe[i - 3]  
                    + safe[i - 4]; 

        return safe[n]; 
    }
```

For example, if i select `n` as `n = 4`, then my results are:

```
4
```

I want to print out those 4 combinations of sums:

```
 1+1+1+1 
 1+3
 3+1 
 4
```

Is there any way to do that either recursively or using dynamic programming?
My try is to get set of combinations recursively :

```
static int[]  Combs(int n)
        {
            int[] tusc = { };

            if (n < 0)
                yield break;
            if (n == 0)
                yield return tusc;
            int[] X = { 1, 3, 4 };
            for(int i = 0; i < X.Length; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j <= Combs(n-X[i]).Length; j++)
                {
                    yield return X + j;
                }

            }

        }
```

Original code that works in python, but don't know how to translate into C#:

```
def combis(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    for x in (1, 3, 4):
        for combi in combis(n-x):
            yield [x] + combi

>>> list(combis(5))
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3], [1, 3, 1], [1, 4], [3, 1, 1], [4, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty direct translation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass 
{
    static IEnumerable<List<int>> Combs(int n)
    {
        if (n < 0)
        {
            yield break;
        } 
        else if (n == 0) 
        {
            yield return new List<int>();
        }

        foreach (int x in new List<int>() {1, 3, 4})
        {
            foreach (IEnumerable<int> combi in Combs(n - x))
            {       
                var result = new List<int>() {x};
                result.AddRange(combi);
                yield return result;
            }

        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<int> nums in Combs(5))
        {
            foreach (var i in nums) 
            {
                Console.Write(i + ", ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 
1, 3, 1, 
1, 4, 
3, 1, 1, 
4, 1,
```

Remarks:

- Since you're using `yield`, change the `Combs` header to return an `IEnumerable<int>` rather than `int[]`.
- Use lists rather than fixed-length arrays and `List.AddRange` to translate the `+` list concatenation operation from Python.
- There is some confusion about translating `X`. In the Python version, `x` is just a single element in the `{1, 3, 4}` options list but in the C# version, it's the whole array.
- `Combs(n-X[i]).Length` doesn't make sense--it calls `Combs`, takes the length of the results and then throws all of the results away, so it's like a really expensive counter. `j` gives you a counter index, not one of the elements from the child `Combs` call as intended. `foreach` is the most accurate translation of Python's `for .. in` loops.
- The `{1, 3, 4}` list should probably be made into a parameter to allow the caller to control its behavior.
- Efficiency is poor because overlapping subproblems are recomputed. Improving it is left as an exercise (this was probably your next step anyway).